# Where is AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios10

In iOS 9, I used the [AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1388007-avplayeritemfailedtoplaytoendtim) notification to update my UI when network problems caused a MP3 stream to stop playing.  I can't seem to find this in iOS 10 with Swift 3.

I want to write code like this (using iOS 10 beta 2):

```
// Fails to compile...
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName:AVPlayerItem.ItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification, 
    object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
    print("Received notification")
}
```

Where is it?  Or, is there a better way to be notified of streaming failures?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3 it's `Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime` Cheers!